# Cannot call a function using <a> in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, dom

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

alert("hello");
$(function viewKart(event) {
    alert("hello");
    $("#popupdiv").dialog({
        title: "AddCart",
        width: 630,
        height: 450,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close')
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>

<div class="text">
    <a id="cartClick" onclick="viewKart();" href="#"> Cart(@if ( @App["CartLen"] != null) { @App["CartLen"] })</a>
</div>

 <div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none">
       <p>Hello World !</p>

    </div>
```

I am trying to call a jquery function but unable to do so. I have a text "Cart(0)" which I want to be a link to view the cart which is actually a pop-up.

Comment: you are passing the function immediately as a jQuery ready. Delete the `$(` wrapper around the function.

Comment: and use `onclick='viewKart'`

Comment: @Amila If you pass a function in the HTML attributes you need to explicitly call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a jQuery wrap around your function.

```js
function viewKart() {
  alert("hello");
  $("#popupdiv").dialog({
    title: "AddCart",
    width: 630,
    height: 450,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close')
      }
    }
  });
  $("#popupdiv").dialog("open")
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="text">
  <a id="cartClick" onclick="viewKart();" href="#"> Cart(...)</a>
</div>

<div id="popupdiv" title="Basic modal dialog" style="display: none">
  <p>Hello World !</p>
</div>
```

Comment: My dialog box is not appearing. I have edited my post for the div containing the data to be appeared.

Comment: Made a couple of changes. You initialised the dialog (but that should probably done on document ready) but didn't actually show the dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Use the power of jQuery handler, and keep clean your html:

#### 1. use `.on("click")` handler, instead a function:

```
    $(function(){
        //alert("Document Ready");
        $("#cartClick").on("click",function(e){
            //alert("Button clicked!!");

            $("#popupdiv").dialog({
                title: "AddCart",
                width: 630,
                height: 450,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close')
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

[jQuery API : .on("click")](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

#### 2. remove `onClick` attribute on your html.

```
    <div class="text">
        <a id="cartClick" href="#"> Cart(@if ( @App["CartLen"] != null) { @App["CartLen"] })</a>
    </div>
```

Every time a user click on element with ID `#cartClick` jQuery trigger your function (anonymous).

*Note. My answer is just for your knowledge, all the others are equally valid.*

Comment: Its not working for me. The <a> tag is in my shared page which is being used by the page having the #popupdiv.

Comment: I'm not sure to have understand :D

Comment: you need to open a dialog, and inside of this you need to load the content of the page linked in the href?

Comment: shared page is like master page in mvc. This master page will show how many items are there in the cart.

Comment: This link will open a dialog box which will show the contents I will get using json. href has nothing to do. I just want to make it as a link which when cllicked opens a dialog.

Comment: Ok, normally my code does what you need. If this code not work fine there are some problem somewhere. Right... have you some error in console? a # is hung to the url when you click on link?

Comment: Ok now control is going inside the function on clicking. Can you help me with the dialog box. It is not appearing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63092/discussion-between-smoking-monkey-and-frogmouth).

Answer (score 0):

The function `viewKart` is not in the global scope

```
alert("hello");
$(viewKart);
function viewKart(event) {
    alert("hello");
    $("#popupdiv").dialog({
        title: "AddCart",
        width: 630,
        height: 450,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('close')
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```